# Not able run three files in protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Config file :

```
qa:   ['./specs/log_in.js','./specs/create_position_roles.js'],
```

using this specs its working fine and also if i run each file individually  it is working fine but if i add one more file like below

```
qa:   ['./specs/log_in.js','./specs/create_project.js','./specs/create_position_roles.js'],
```

it is not working.

I am getting error like this:

> ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 1):

*The state of the browser is shared across the tests* which means that what a previous test can affect the subsequent tests. For instance, if you log into the application in the `log_in.js` and don't logout, you'll stay logged when `create_project.js` test starts. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am not logging out. Until  last Friday evening everything was working fine and now am facing this problem.  If i run each file individually it is working fine. Please help me